# Script Batch para Reiniciar Serviço AnyDesk

Tags: batch

Preciso criar um scrpit batch que grava o status do AnyDesk em uma varíavel e de tempo em tempo, se estiver com o status 'offline' ele reinicia o serviço do AnyDesk.
Exemplo:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --get-status') do set CID=%%i 
echo AnyDesk status is: %CID%
pause
```

Neste exemplo ele grava o status do AnyDesk na variável CID, com isso preciso fazer laço de comando que quando o status for diferente de online ele reinicia o serviço com o comando abaixo:
AnyDesk --restart-service

Answer (score 0):

1. Testar o valor da variável

```
if /i not "%CID%" == "online" "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --restart-service
```

ou

```
if /i "%CID%" == "offline" "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --restart-service
```

2. Para simular um laço de tempo em tempo

```
:VOLTA
@REM Coloque os comandos depois desta linha

PING 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
@GOTO :VOLTA
```